# R: Creating a function with an arbitrarily long expression

Tags: r, function, for-loop

Although my original question is more general, in order to keep things more comprehensive, I'm formulating below just its partial case, - I expect that a solution/ answer for it will serve as an answer for the more general question.

Question:

- **to integrate a function  f(x)=(...(((x^x)^x)^x)...^x)^x (... powered x n times) on the interval (0,1)** ?

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

P.S.: please, do not try to solve the problem mathematically or to simplify an expression (e.g., to approximate the result with a Taylor expansion, whatever), since it's not the main topic (however, I've tried to choose such an example, which should not have any simple transformations)

P.S.2: Original question (which does not require an answer here, since it's expected that an answer for posted question is valid for original one):

*if it's possible in R to create a function with an arbitrarily long expression* (avoiding "manual" defining). For example, it's easy to set up *manually* a given function for n=5:

```
f<-function(x) {
((((x^x)^x)^x)^x)^x
}
```

*But what if n=1'000, or 1'000'000* ?
It seems that simple looping  is not appropriate here...

Comment: It is considered bad form to cross-post on SO and Rhelp on the same day.

Comment: Would `foo <- function(f, x, n) Reduce(f, rep(x, n))` work? Where `foo("^", 2, 3)` computes `2^2^2`. If that's what you mean, I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @flodel: I think it should actually read `(2^2)^2` (which for the case of `x=2` happens to also be `2^2^2`).

Comment: @flodel: thank you for the idea, probably, I had to mention that already thought about <funprog (Reduce)> and simple <for> looping approaches. But with both approaches I can only compute a value of a function given a value of inputs. That's why in the posted question I'm asking to take an integral. For example, if I have `fun <- function(x) Reduce("+", rep(x, 5) )`, then `integrate(fun, 0, 1)` would produce an error message: `evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length`.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong, so, maybe your solution with Integration would answer my question fully. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Copied from Rhelp: You should look at:

```
 # ?funprog   Should have worked but didn't. Try instead ...
 ?Reduce
```

There are several examples of repeated applications of a functional argument. Also composition of list of functions.

One instance:

```
Funcall <- function(f, ...) f(...)  # sort of like `do.call`
Iterate <- function(f, n = 1)
   function(x) Reduce(Funcall, rep.int(list(f), n), x, right = TRUE)

Iterate(function(x) x^1.1, 30)(1.01)
#[1] 1.189612
```